# I am having issues extracting hindi text from pdf in python

Tags: python, pdfplumber

I am using pdfplumber in python..
It is not extracting hindi text well. It is showing wrong results.
input :माँ, मैं रात का खाना ले आऊँगा।
output:  म ,ाँ म ैं र त क ख न ले आऊाँग ।
I want the exact output..
Any solution ??

Comment: MRE is needed (provide Your take on the issue) what is Your code

Comment: Have you asked in the `discussion` section of their [Github page](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber/discussions)?